# memcpy() and memmove() not working as expected

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I ran into this problem while working with a struct array within a struct. I'm trying to set the entry array in the dict using memcpy. I'm getting a mixture of the expected values and some seemingly random integers as output.

Oddly enough, I tried this code with some online compilers, and it worked fine. I thought that it might have to do with overlapping memory regions, so I tried memmove() but the result was the same.

I think I might be using malloc improperly for the dict, but I'm not sure. It seems I can't use malloc for the internal array, or for the individual elements. I'd appreciate any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    int i;
} entry;

typedef struct{
    entry e[10];
    int i;
} dict;

dict* d;

void test(dict* di){
    printf("%d\n", di->i);
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < 10; k ++){
        printf(("%d\n"),di->e[k].i);
    }
}

int main(){
    entry en[10];

    d = malloc(sizeof(d));

    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < 10; k++){
        en[k].i = k;
    }

    d->i = 50; 
    memcpy(d->e, en, 10*sizeof(entry));

    test(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `d` is a pointer. And as such you are getting the size of a pointer, not a struct. Use `sizeof(dict)`.

Comment: The idomatic way for `malloc`-ing memory for a single object pointed by pointer `d` is `d = malloc(sizeof *d)`. What happened to the `*` in your code?

Comment: @Paul Rooney: There's no such type as `struct dict` in the OP's code.

Comment: yes correct. I didnt read it properly. I just presumed it would be defined that way.

Comment: Thank you both, that was the problem.

Comment: valgrind is a cool tool, it would have shown that bug immediately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
d = malloc(sizeof(d));
```

`d` is a `dict*`; `sizeof d` is `sizeof(dict*)`. Looks like you meant `sizeof *d`.